# BATCH- binary with for

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd

I have to make a script that has to calculate the mask and the net, so I'm trying a script with for but it can not convert the IP to binary. I think I'm not using the variables right.

Any ideas?

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

set var=%1  
set /p var=Introduce la ip:   

for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("%var%") do (  

    echo %%a  
    set "vara=%%a"  
    :binario  
    set bin=2  
    set /a resto=%vara%%%bin%  
    set /a a=%vara%/%bin%  
    set resultado=%resto%%resultado%  
    if %vara% GTR 0 (goto binario)  
    echo %resultado%  
    goto siguiente  
    )  
    :siguiente  
for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%b in ("%var%") do (  
    echo %%b  
    )  
for /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%c in ("%var%") do (  
    echo %%c  
    )  
for /F "tokens=4 delims=." %%d in ("%var%") do (  
    echo %%d  
    )  

goto fin  

:vacio  
echo Error!  
goto fin  

:fin  
pause
```

Comment: when you use delayed expansion and brackets you need to access your variables with `!` instead of `%`.

Comment: also using `GOTO` witin FOR will break the FOR context.

Comment: check this http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=22370#p22370

Comment: This line: `set /a resto=%vara%%%bin%` I think might cause problems.  Not sure.  In batch scripts, when you want a literal `%`, you need to use `%%` to prevent batch from evaluating it as a variable identifier.  Also, your code will be more readable if you drop the percents around your variables in your `set /a` lines.  This is allowed with `set /a`.  Try `set /a resto = vara %% bin`.  See how much cleaner that looks?  You obviously can't do that with `set "variable=%string%"`, but `set /a` works a little differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few minor problems that I see.  You set `var=%1` but you never check to see whether %1 was supplied before doing `set /p var=Enter an IP:`.  You never call or goto `:vacio`.  As I commented above, modulos within batch scripts need to be written as `%%` to prevent evaluation as variable chararacters.  You don't need `%` in var names in `set /a` commands, and you can combine multiple `set /a` statements with a comma.  So instead of

```
set /a resto=%vara%%%bin%
set /a a=%vara%/%bin%
```

(which is wrong anyway -- I'll get to that in a minute), I suggest this would be more understandable and maintainable:

```
set /a resto = vara %% bin, numero = vara / bin
```

The biggest problem is that you appear to be trying to modify `%%a`.  Don't do that.

If I were you, I would move the decimal to binary conversion to a subroutine, and call it for each octet.  Try this:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  

set IP=%1

if "%IP%"=="" set /p "IP=Introduce la ip: "

set idx=0

for %%a in (%IP:.= %) do (

    if %%a lss 0 goto vacio
    if %%a gtr 255 goto vacio
    if !idx! gtr 3 goto vacio

    set /P "=%%a = "<NUL
    call :dec2bin bin[!idx!] %%a
    set /a idx += 1
)

echo %bin[0]%.%bin[1]%.%bin[2]%.%bin[3]%
goto fin

:dec2bin <var_para_definir> <numero>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set numero=%~2
set bin=
for /L %%I in (1,1,8) do (
    set /a bit = numero %% 2, numero /= 2
    set bin=!bit!!bin!
)
echo %bin%
endlocal & set "%~1=%bin%"
goto :EOF

:vacio  
echo Error!  
goto fin  

:fin  
pause
```

For more information about using `call` as a function that returns a value, [see this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php).

Comment: thank you very much!!! I'm using batch for 2 months now for class and it's been a real struggle!! you helped me a lot!

Comment: One question though.. I need to use the first octet to calculate the mask and some bits from the right to calculate the net, how can  I separate them? thank you!!

Comment: The first octet is in `%bin[0]%`.  The last octet is `%bin[3]%`.  If you want the right-most four bits of the last octet, `%bin[3]:~-4%` will get you what you want.  [See this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more similar examples of substring extraction from variables.  Is this what you are asking?